# celerybeat docker paho mqtt

Tags: python, celery, mqtt, paho

my use case is, that I read a csv file and send these data via mqtt to a hivemq broker.
When I start the celery worker and the clerybeat `locally` (change rabbitmq and hivemq to localhost), everything works fine and I get the data in `mqttFX Client`. It does not work with the Docker-Configuration. The two worker and the celerybeat start correctly and in the method `send_mqtt` the inner function `on_publish` is called.

When I start it with the docker-compose file I get no data in my mqttFX client. The worker can connect to `RabbitMQ` and `HiveMQ`...I think...

Sum up: Everything works when I start the celeryworkers and the celerybeat in 3 terminals. It just does not work with my Docker-Configuration.

**app.py**

```
from celery import Celery
import pandas as pd
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import datetime
import json

celery = Celery('app', broker='rabbitmq')

current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
filepath = f'/var/lib/excel/{current_date}.csv'


celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "readcsv-task": {
        "task": "app.read_csv",
        "schedule": 10.0,
        "args": (filepath,),
    }
}

celery.conf.task_routes = ([
    ('app.read_csv', {'queue': 'csv'}),
    ('app.send_mqtt', {'queue': 'mqtt'}),
],)


@celery.task()
def send_mqtt(data):

    def on_publish(client, userdata, result):
        print("data published \n")
        pass

    topic = 'data/mqtt/'
    client = mqtt.Client("ExcelService")
    client.on_publish = on_publish
    client.connect('hivemq', 1883)

    mqtt_data = data.encode('utf-8')
    client.publish(topic, mqtt_data)
    print(f'mqtt data {mqtt_data} send, type {type(mqtt_data)}')


@celery.task()
def read_csv(filepath):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";")
        last_row = df.tail(1)

        value_id = int(last_row.iloc[0][0])
        payload = int(last_row.iloc[0][2])
        date = str(last_row.iloc[0][1])

        data = {
            "id": value_id,
            "payload": payload,
            "date": date
        }

        mqtt_data = json.dumps(data)
        send_mqtt.delay(mqtt_data)

    except IOError:
        print(f'No file "{filepath}" found. Restart in 10sec.')
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  excelservice:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../excel/:/var/lib/excel   
    networks:
      - test
    restart: always    
    depends_on:
      - hivemq
      - rabbitmq

  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "test-rabbitmq"
    restart: always    
    labels:
      NAME: "test-rabbitmq"
    networks:
      - test
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"

  hivemq:
    container_name: hivemq
    image: hivemq/hivemq3
    restart: always    
    networks:
      - test
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "8080:8080"

networks: 
  test: {}
```

**Start-script 4 celery worker and celerybeat:**

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo "Wait for RabbitMQ to start..." 
sleep 15
echo "Start csvworker..." &
celery worker -A app --pool=eventlet -Q csv -n csvworker@%h --loglevel=INFO &
sleep 5 
echo "Start mqttworker..." &
celery worker -A app --pool=eventlet -Q mqtt -n mqttworker@%h --loglevel=INFO &
sleep 5 
echo "Start celerybeat..." &
celery -A app beat --loglevel=info
```

**Dockerfile 4 app.py**

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code

ADD ./prod_start.sh /usr/local/bin/prod_start.sh
RUN dos2unix /usr/local/bin/prod_start.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/prod_start.sh
ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/prod_start.sh
```

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

I changed the celery.task -> send_mqtt and put the client initalisation out of the method and it works. maybe someone can explain me, why this is working?

**new app.py**

```
from celery import Celery
import pandas as pd
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import datetime
import json

# celery = Celery('app', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//')
celery = Celery('app', broker='rabbitmq')

current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
filepath = f'/var/lib/excel/{current_date}.csv'


celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "readcsv-task": {
        "task": "app.read_csv",
        "schedule": 10.0,
        "args": (filepath,),
    }
}

celery.conf.task_routes = ([
    ('app.read_csv', {'queue': 'csv'}),
    ('app.send_mqtt', {'queue': 'mqtt'}),
],)


def on_publish(client, userdata, result):
    print("data published \n")
    pass

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("client disconnected ok")


def on_log(client, obj, level, string):
    print(string)


client = mqtt.Client("ExcelService")
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.on_log = on_log
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect


@celery.task()
def send_mqtt(data):

    topic = 'data/mqtt/'
    client.connect('hivemq', 1883)

    mqtt_data = data.encode('UTF-8')
    client.publish(topic, mqtt_data)
    # client.disconnect()

    print(f'mqtt data {mqtt_data} send, type {type(mqtt_data)}')


@celery.task()
def read_csv(filepath):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";")
        last_row = df.tail(1)

        value_id = int(last_row.iloc[0][0])
        payload = int(last_row.iloc[0][2])
        date = str(last_row.iloc[0][1])

        data = {
            "id": value_id,
            "payload": payload,
            "date": date
        }

        mqtt_data = json.dumps(data)
        send_mqtt.delay(mqtt_data)

    except IOError:
        print(f'No file "{filepath}" found. Restart in 10sec.')
```

Comment: It "smells" to me like a networking issue...

Comment: i have no clue whats going on. How would you start to debug this case? thank youu